# How to configure MX pointing to VPS

Tags: vps, mx-record

This is new stuff for me, so bear with me!

I already have a domain (let's say for example xyz.com). This domain is hosted on a shared environment, so there is no way for us to send aprox 30.000 emails/day from this hoster (a small one in Athens/Greece).

So we thought to buy a VPS and setup there ONLY an Email server for sending out the emails. So my question is:

Supposed the VPS has the IP: 17.18.19.20
How do I change/add the MX records to the VPS?  (the DNS entries already have two MX records 
mail.xyz.com and mail2.xyz.com pointing to the A record )

Would I have to:

1. Add an A record which points to 17.18.19.20 eg server2.xyz.com and then,
2. Add an MX record which points to server.xyz.com and has a name like mail3.xyz.com ?

Comment: 30k emails a day? Hire a service that does this. It's far more work that you can imagine to be able to send that volume without being flagged immediately, no matter how well prepared you are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MX records determine where email is sent TO, not where it's sent FROM. If this server will not be receiving email for your domain then you shouldn't make any changes to the MX records. If this server will be sending email for your domain then you need to create/modify your SPF record.

Comment: The sole purpose of the email server will be to send the emails away. I already have a SPF record:   v=spf1 a mx -all . How do i have to change this?

Comment: I believe that "v=spf1 a mx ip4:x.x.x.x -all", where x.x.x.x is the IPv4 address of the server should do it.